# Android: Linkify inside a list adapter works only for the first item

Tags: android, listadapter, linkify, autolink

I have this annoying problem.

I have a list adapter which contains a TextView.

In my TextView, the text is defined to be a link to a phone by using XML.
It works well on the first item of of the list but not on the other items.

Any ideas?

Here is my XML snippet:

```
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/phone"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/phone"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:autoLink="phone"
                android:textSize="@dimen/feed_item_phone" />
```

And getView code snippet:

```
        TextView phone = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.phone);
        phone.setText(item.getPhone());
```

Thanks!

Comment: Where hv u written code for linkify?

Comment: @NayanSrivastava At the XML by using autoLink. Even when I used Lankily inside Java, it did not help :(